# Cake PHP: Find condition on deeper level of recursion

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

My Models are related as follows:

```
Post BELONGS_TO Parent
Parent HAS_MANY ParentAdmin
```

Now I wish to find all Parent admins of all post if a post's attribute's value is met. The equivalent sql query is :

```
SELECT parent_admins.* FROM posts 
LEFT JOIN parents AS Parent ON Parent.id = posts.target_id    
LEFT JOIN parent_admins ON parent_admins.parent_id = Parent.id 
WHERE posts.admin_notification = 0 AND Parent.maxtime > posts.created
```

Assuming Models are linked in cakephp accordingly and `recursive = 2`, what will be the condition array in find query?

Answer (score 2):

You can both use the [bindModel](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-Model.html#_bindModel) & [unbindModel](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-Model.html#_unbindModel) methods to get the exact query you want or you can use the [`Containable` behavior](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html).

More information about how to create and destroy associations on the fly with CakePHP: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#creating-and-destroying-associations-on-the-fly

And you'll need this array of conditions:

```
$conditions = array(
    'Post.admin_notification' => 0,
    'Parent.maxtime >' => 'Post.created'
);
```

Comment: Assuming the models are bound properly. I need to know what will be the conditions array value to achieve that sql query.

Answer (score 0):

according to your query :-

```
$conditions=array(
                 'posts.admin_notification'=>0,
                 'Parent.maxtime >'=>'posts.created'
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

If your query do the job:
Inside PostsController:

```
    $query = "SELECT parent_admins.* FROM posts 
    LEFT JOIN parents AS Parent ON Parent.id = posts.target_id    
    LEFT JOIN parent_admins ON parent_admins.parent_id = Parent.id 
    WHERE posts.admin_notification = 0 AND Parent.maxtime > posts.created"

    $result = $this->Posts->query($query);
    $debug($result);
```